# php file upload returning error 6 even though tmpdir is set

Tags: php, file, file-upload, image-upload

php file upload returning error 6 even though tmpdir is set in php.ini and all paths are correct. My code is too long to be posted but here's the part where it handles the file

```
$uploaddir = __DIR__ . '/img/';

        echo $_FILES['navpic']['error'];

        if($_FILES['navpic']['size'] != 0) {
            $navpic = $uploaddir . "navpic.png";
            if($_FILES['navpic']['size'] < 1000000) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['navpic']['tmp_name'], $navpic)) {
                    $navpicupload = 0;
                } else
                    $navpicupload = 1;
            } else {
                $navpicupload = 2;
            }
        } else {
            $navpicupload = 1;
        }
```

//edit I also have permission to write in both directories so thats neither the problem
:/

Comment: According to this URL: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php your error is value 6 meaning that you are missing a temporary folder. Then on this URL: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir it says: "Must be writable by whatever user PHP is running as". Please make sure that the folder you are uploading to does exist and is writable by the webserver.

Comment: what is your php & OS version? Though Error :6 means " UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR    Value: 6; Missing a temporary folder."

Comment: I said I checked all of these sites and I made sure the user running apache has permission in both folders, every folder exists and the paths are correct so I don't understand why it says error 6. I am pretty sure it's not the code, more like the configuration of the server...